# Fill only the elements in the top and bottom row with zeroes

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python statement for performing the following task with a table of m rows and n columns.

I have to fill only the top row and bottom row with zeros.

So far I have:

```
list = []
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
```

I'm not sure what to do next. How can I access just the first and last row? Thank you!

Comment: can you provide more details ? like data and the code that you have written ?

Comment: What do you want in the other cells?

Comment: I wasn't given any data. Just that m is rows and n is columns

Comment: Anything can be in the other cells

Comment: Are you allowed to use numpy, or does it have to be in pure Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
lst = [[0 if i in (0, m-1) else default_val] * n for i in range(m)]
```

That roughly does the same as:

```
lst = []  # do not shadow 'list'
for i in range(m):
    lst[i] = []
    for j in range(n):
        lst[i].append(0 if i in (0, m-1) else default_val)
```

Comment: LOL, usually it is me pointing this exact thing out to others :) For mutable objects you'd have to the comprehension for the inner lists as well.

Comment: Nah, if you did sth like `[X()] * n` you'd get n references to the same `X` object

Comment: Aah, yes, yes. I got you now.

Answer (score 0):

Code based on your provided information :

```
list = []
for x in range(0, m):
    if x == 0 or x == m:
        # your code for filling it with zeros
    else:
        # your code for "Anything can be in other cells"
```

Comment: so under if x == 0 or x == m: do I add list.append([0])